# Spring integration ip - udp channel with java code only

Tags: java, spring, udp, ip, spring-integration

I've been looking at the Spring integration ip module, I wanted to create UDP channel for receiving, but I found I can only do it with XML. 
I was thinking that I could make something out if I looked inside the implementation code, but it creates bean definition itself, from parameters supplied in xml.
I can't use xml definitions in my code, is there a way to make it work with spring without xml?

alternatively, is there any better way in java to work with udp?

Comment: turns out, as pointed in answer, I was looking at UdpInboundChannelAdapterParser instead of org.springframework.integration.ip.udp.UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version `5.0` there is Java DSL on the matter already, so the code for UDP Channel Adapters may look like:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inUdpAdapter() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Udp.inboundAdapter(0))
                .channel(udpIn())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel udpIn() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outUdpAdapter() {
        return f -> f.handle(Udp.outboundAdapter(m -> m.getHeaders().get("udp_dest")));
    }
```

But with existing Spring Integration version you can simply configure `UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter` bean:

```
@Bean
public UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter udpInboundAdapter() {
        UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter unicastReceivingChannelAdapter = new UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter(1111);
        unicastReceivingChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(udpChannel());
        return unicastReceivingChannelAdapter;
}
```

In the Reference Manual you can find the [Tips and Tricks](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips) chapter for some info how to write Spring Integration application with raw Java and annotation configuration.

I added [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4279) to address Java sample in the Reference Manual.

Comment: wow, works like a charm, thank you :) How did you find it/figure out you have to use it? ... upd: looked at the profile, now makes some sense :)